# Paymill pre-create card payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paymill

Is there a way to pre-create a card payment for Paymill? When creating a Paymill Payment object we need a token, this token is got by provide card info and **amount/currency**. With the first transaction of this payment object, Paymill require the same ammount/currency as the value we use to get the token. So the user can't create a payment for future transaction because they don't know how much they pay for the first transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in the following way. Create a token with an amount/currency for example 100 Euro (but not smaller than 1 Euro!). Afterwards make directly with this token a preauth transaction. You get an paymentobjectid as response and the creditcard is checked if it is valid and has at this time the wanted amount (limit is not exceeded). This preauth is valid for 7 days and afterwards it is deleted automatically or your make a reversal of the preauth. With the paymentobjectid you can than make another recurring payment with a different amount.

Best,
Christian